# Exporting a native struct definition to managed code

Tags: c#, c++-cli, interop, clr

I have a native type in a C++/CLI assembly and a managed function that accepts that type.

```cpp
#pragma unmanaged
struct NativeStruct
{
    int foo;
};

#pragma managed
#pragma make_public(NativeStruct)

void DoStuff(NativeStruct ns)
{
    // ...
}
```

In plain C# I want to be able to create a `NativeStruct`, set `foo`, and pass it to `DoSomething()`. Using `make_public` ensures the type is public and can be used on a C# side. C# knows the correct size and I can even create an instance. However, C# doesn't know anything about the members of `NativeStruct`.

```cs
// C#
void SendMessage()
{
    var ns = new NativeStruct();
    ns.foo = 1; // Error!
    DoStuff(ns);
}
```

I can confirm this by looking at the metadata for `NativeStruct` in the VS Object Browser. The type is present, but the field `foo` is not.

I could create a copy of the struct in C# using `StructLayoutAttribute`, but there is going to be a few dozen of these structs and I was expecting the C++/CLI compiler to output the equivalent data automatically.

Is there anyway to get the compile to create the full struct definition for use in C#?

Comment: This cannot work, the struct is empty by design to stop you from doing this.  Marshaling is *always* required to copy an unmanaged struct to a managed one, Marshal.PtrToStructure().  You can lessen the pain of having to duplicate the structure declarations with a code generator tool like SWIG.

Comment: "to copy an unmanaged struct to a managed one" I don't follow this part. There's no managed struct. There's also not necessarily any copying, as it'd be fine to pass the native struct by reference. The native struct will always be POD and blittable types.

Comment: "There is no managed struct" is the problem, you must have one to allow C# code to access the struct content.  Inconvenient, no doubt, but required.

Comment: It's surprising that the compiler goes through all the trouble of creating a managed placeholder class with the correct size and none of the fields. Am I even going to be able to reuse a simple native enum at this rate?

Comment: You know the answer to that one as well, inconvenient.